# How to make two edittext on alertdialog android and keep in arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist, layout

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement

    if (id == R.id.action_add) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        builder.setTitle("Tambah Daftar");
        final View formsView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detailbarang, null, false);
        final EditText barang = (EditText) formsView.findViewById(R.id.nama_barang);
        final EditText harga = (EditText) formsView.findViewById(R.id.harga_barang);
        builder.setView(barang);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if (barang.getText().toString().equals("") && (harga.getText().toString().equals(""))) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Teks Kosong, Masukkan teks", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {
                    ListData.add(preferredCase(barang.getText().toString())+ harga.getText().toString());
                    storeArrayVal(ListData, getApplicationContext());
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Berhasil", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                }

            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Batal", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        builder.show();
        return true;
    }
```

it was always forced close when i want to use the action_add function.
it's start when i add function layoutinfleter for my layout.xml for alert dialog
maybe someone can help me how to use correctly function to use in my layout.xml to alert dialog.
thx before.

Comment: Can you post what the logcat shows when it forced close?

Answer (score 0):

use `dialog.cancel();` after if else scope

you have to close dialog after performing your action

Answer (score 0):

**remove builder.setView(barang) and do it like this**

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
    builder.setTitle("yoyo");
    final View formsView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog,null,false);
    final EditText barang=(EditText)formsView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    final EditText harga=(EditText)formsView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    builder.setView(formsView);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which){
            if(barang.getText().toString().equals("")&&(harga.getText().toString().equals(""))){
                Toast.makeText(ctx,"first",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }else{


                Toast.makeText(ctx,"show",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Batal",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which){
            dialog.cancel();
            Toast.makeText(ctx,"cancel",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    builder.show();
```